# Find Matrix $A\vec{x}$ with one eigenvector and one eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is a $2\times 2$ Matrix.  $\vec{x} = 
\begin{pmatrix}-3\\
7 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector and $\lambda_{1} = 3$
is an eigenvalue.
I need to find $A\vec{x}$.

I am unsure how to do this and would like a little direction. This is a non-graded practice problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Ax = \lambda x
$$
The eigenvector $x$ and its corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ must satisfy the above equation.

If you are looking to find $Ax$, then you just multiply the given: $\lambda x=3\cdot[-3, 7]^{\top} = [-9, 21]^{\top}$, where the notation $\top$ means the transpose. So your answer is a column vector with $2$ entries.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think I am following the notation of the ^{T}. I am expecting A to be a 2x2 matrix also

Comment: Are you looking for $Ax$? or $A$? The notation is just a transpose.

Comment: Ax. I'm fighting with the editing too.

Comment: Okay, so the main equation you are looking for is $Ax = \lambda x$. Any eigenvalue &vector pair must satisfy this.

Comment: js9 is saying that, since you already have the eigenvector and the eigenvalue, you don't need to calculate $A$ in order to know $Ax$.

Comment: He's also pointing out that I am making this more confusing. I am looking for A, not Ax, which is why I wasn't following. The answer I want will be a 2x2 matrix, unless I misunderstand the worksheet.

Comment: I am answering based on your question. Perhaps you can copy and paste your worksheet verbatim. If you have a second eigenvalue and its eigenvector, please provide. Then you can reconstruct the matrix $A$. If not, I believe the question is asking for $Ax$.

Comment: Also, I asked in my first comment if you were looking for $A$ or $Ax$ and you said $Ax$. I don’t know why you are contradicting yourself.

Comment: @js9 I tried to explain that I made a mistake in my first comment. If you don't care to help me because I made that mistake, then go help someone else. If I may be allowed to make the mistake -- and apologize for the confusion, as I tried to - and you feel like pointing me in the right direction, then do so. Your choice.

Comment: @Ron, what part of my comment does it look like I don't care to help you?
I asked for clarification, and then I answered based on your input in the comment. Some moments later you commented again that you were actually looking for something different from your initial question. Okay, that's fine, and that's why I asked if you have more info (second eigenvalue & eigenvector) then I can find $A$.

Also, I don't know why you feel that way but I never was "pointing out" that you are making this more confusing. Your title is different from your text, and that is why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @js9 First, I did edit the title, you were right it disagreed with the body of the question. I was having issues with MathJax (this is probably my third question on this forum in my life). Second, the phrase "contradict yourself" comes across as a loaded statement and I had admitted I had made that mistake and attempted to apologize for it. Finally, the question I posed is nearly verbatim the question from the worksheet. There is no second eigenvector nor a second eigenvalue. If I had those, I would be able to solve the equation. I thought there might be a way to eliminate the variables.

Comment: @Ron, Okay, it's understandable. I apologize if that sounded loaded as you say, it's not. I was simply referring to your first clarification. I suggested an edit to the question, please take a look. If it says "matrix $Ax$" then the question written on the worksheet is wrong unless $x$ is also a matrix, which is not.

Now, the original post answers your intended question. So, can I help you with anything else? If not, please kindly close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Recap: A matrix can be viewed as a linear map, rotating and transforming space in such a way that all grid lines remain parallel, and the angles between them the same.

Eigenvectors are like "special directions" in which any vector pointing along that direction will only get stretched (not rotated) by a certain scalar--which is the eigenvalue. For more visual intuition, you should definitely [3Blue1Brown's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g) on the topic. It's very well explained.

Taking a look at the formula:

$$ Ax = \lambda x $$

This is saying if a matrix $A$ acts upon a certain vector $x$, and ends up only having the effect of *scaling* $x$ by a certain factor, then $x$ would be called an eigenvector of that matrix. And that certain factor would be the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

You are told $x$ is an eigenvector, and 3 is its eigenvalue (in your post it says 'an' eigenvalue, but I assume they are a pair)

That would mean $Ax$ is equivalent to just $3x$. Which would be $\begin{pmatrix} -9 \\ 21 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Don't say "equivalent" when you mean "equal" (or vice-versa). :)

Comment: @TedShifrin ah good point, I used to use them pretty much interchangeably until you just motivated me to look up the difference ;) thanks